# Updating/Replacing file in a zip folder with a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, tableau-api, unzip, zip

I need to replace/update an excel file which is in a zip folder but I dont want to unzip it before. Is there any way to do it without unzipping it?
Because the folder contains a tableau dashboard which is going to crash after unzipping and zipping it again.

Comment: You can open the zipfile in "a" and add the excel file. You'll now have the old and new file in the archive with the same name. During extraction one will overwrite the other but Its anybody's guess which one wins. You'll likely get a prompt when extracting. But suppose software just grabs the first one and never checks for duplicates? You are better off building a new file. I don't understand how a dashboard is going to crash, details?

Comment: The dashboard is saved as a twbx file which is equivalent to a zip file. 
I tried to unzip, change the files and zip again. After that it didnt work.
Without zipping and just changing the files, worked out for me. Strange I know...

Comment: Why it is tagged under `Tableau`?

Comment: because it is a twbx file where I need to replace the data source without unzipping the folder